# How to narrow element type of a Vector or Array in Julia?

Tags: julia

Consider a situation where I first create a Vector with `eltype` of `Any` incrementally; after that, I want to narrow the element type of it. How can I do that?

```
julia> vec = Any[1, 2, 3.]
3-element Vector{Any}:
 1
 2
 3.0
```

I can use something like `convert(Vector{Real}, vec)`. But in this case, I'm specifying the type manually while I want Julia to decide the best suitable `eltype` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small type unions (such as `Union{Int, Float64}` are handled in Julia much faster and than abstract types and hence you should avoid vectors of abstract elements such as `Vector{Real}` in favor of unions of concrete types such as `Union{Int, Float64}`.

Having that said here is a code that makes such union:

```
julia> Vector{Union{Set(typeof.(vec))...}}(vec)
3-element Vector{Union{Float64, Int64}}:
 1
 2
 3.0
```

And here is a simple test that shows that for a 100 element vector the performance difference is 4x:

```
julia> a1 = Vector{Union{Int, Float64}}(rand(100));

julia> a2 = Vector{Real}(rand(100));

julia> @btime minimum($a1);
  428.643 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime minimum($a2);
  2.000 μs (102 allocations: 1.59 KiB)
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by broadcasting the [`identity`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.identity) function on each element of the given container (either an `Array` or a `Vector`):

```
julia> narrowed = identity.(vec)
3-element Vector{Real}:
 1
 2
 3.0
```

Note that this doesn't lead to promoting (or demoting) the type of each individual element of the given container:

```
julia> typeof(narrowed[1]), typeof(narrowed[3])
(Int64, Float64)
```

## Additional Point

However, in the case of acquainting with related functions in Julia, This can be done verbosely by using the [`typejoin`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.typejoin) function to achieve the type join of the container's elements. According to the concise doc of the function:

> typejoin(T, S)
> Return the closest common ancestor of T and S, i.e. the narrowest type from which they both inherit.

The argument of the `typejoin` should be a subtype of `Core.Type{T}` (However, it seems more sensible to define it as `typejoin(T...)` since it can get an indefinite number of positional arguments, not just two.)

```
julia> typeof.(vec)
3-element Vector{DataType}:
 Int64
 Int64
 Float64

julia> typejoin(typeof.(vec)...)
Real

julia> convert(Vector{typejoin(typeof.(vec)...)}, vec)
3-element Vector{Real}:
 1
 2
 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `promote` like this:

```
v = Any[1, 2, 3.0]
first.(promote.(v))
3-element Vector{Real}:
 1
 2
 3.0000

v = Any[1, 2, 3.0, 3 + 2im]
first.(promote.(v))
4-element Vector{Number}:
   1
   2
   3.0000
 3 + 2im
```

But, you might be interested more in getting a vector of concrete supertypes of the elements, especially for performance purposes. So, you can use this:

```
v = Any[1, 2, 3.0]
reduce(vcat, promote(v...))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

v = Any[1, 2, 3.0, 3 + 2im]
reduce(vcat, promote(v...))
4-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
 1.0 + 0.0im
 2.0 + 0.0im
 3.0 + 0.0im
 3.0 + 2.0im
```

Or, simply:

```
v = Any[1, 2, 3.0];

[v...]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

v = Any[1, 2, 3.0, 3+2im];

[v...]
4-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
 1.0 + 0.0im
 2.0 + 0.0im
 3.0 + 0.0im
 3.0 + 2.0im
```

Comment: Comprehension also works for the first option: `[i for i in v]`.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not narrowing. This is literally promoting. You're changing the elements.